# On-chain sorting optimization

Tags: solidity

I have array of structures on-chain and need to sort it. I used one of that quicksort algorithms that easily can be found and adopted it to use structures instead of plain `uint`s. But I dislike it because it requires "swap" operation - change places of 2 items is the array. With structures it is possible only by creating memory instance like `MyStruct memory temp` and copy one of swappables there, then replace it and put memory-stored one into copied place. It is expensive.

I though that I could use mapping like `mapping (uint16 => MyStruct) list` and then just "swap keys". But it seems that with mapping I have to to the same - copy values because I cannot change key values.

Am I missed something or mapping cannot helps me here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot swap keys in your example, that would result in creating new mapping entries, with high cost as you already said. 
But you could use the mapping `mapping (uint16 => MyStuct) list` to store the data, while you put your keys (the `uint16` values) in an array. You can sort the keys in the array then, the swap operation there will be cheaper. The data itself will be read from the mapping.

Comment: Yes, it was my "plan B" - store indices in additional array and store structs in array too (I don't need mapping here either) and sort only array with indices. Thanks.